# Omniauth-facebook: login popup not redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, omniauth

I moved to omniauth-facebook and it is working wonderfully. I've been trying to use popups for the login button but I can't get it to work.

I followed the example on https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/blob/master/example/config.ru for a rails app.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId  : '#{ENV['APP_ID']}',
          status : true, // check login status
          cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          oauth  : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
          xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
        });
      };

      (function(d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
      }(document));

      $(function() {
        $('a').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
              $.get('/auth/facebook/callback');
            }
          }, { scope: '#{SCOPE}' });
        });
      });
    </script>

    <p>
      <a href="#">Connect to FB</a>
    </p>
```

It almost works: clicking on the link will display the popup and I get authenticated, but when the popup closes I remain on the login page, even though I can see in the logs that the destination page is processed, and if I click on a link that's available both to guests and members, I will get the member version, another proof that the login worked.

So why isn't the browser redirected even though the login is successful ? Should I modify something in the controller method that logs the user in (like a "respond_to" with a special format) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When a user logs in via `FB.login` the dialog closes and the user goes back to the main window, and the callback is invoked.

In your callback you do `$.get('/auth/facebook/callback');`, which is an ajax call.

Where's the redirect?

Comment: The redirect is in the controller method called by /auth/facebook/callback (UserSessionsControler#create_with_provider).

Comment: It's an ajax request, which by itself doesn't change the page, and it's actually weird because you're [getting something from the server](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) but you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: Well I thought I'd be doing something with by using a respond_to with a format.js and a redirection in it but it's not called, when I track what's happening it goes through format.html. Or should I render a rjs view that reloads the page ?

Comment: Usually this code is added: `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) { window.location.reload(); });`. If you only want to reload on login you don't need any ajax, just reload --but then again, I obviously have very limited insight on your code

Comment: Well, replacing "$.get('/auth/facebook/callback');" with "window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback';" worked, but then I tried in another browser and got "invalid-credentials" with that login method, while a regular button would log me in. Also tried to add FB.Event.subscribe but it never was triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Add `:authorize_params => { :display => 'popup' }` to the provider info for facebook in your initializer.